# Strange FormatException after upgrading in VS 2010

Tags: c#-4.0, formatexception

I get this FormatException after i upgraded to VS 2010. Not anything really special.
Code:

```
private void ManageDateEditControls()
{
    apoDateEdit.DateTime = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("01/{0}/{1}", DateTime.Now.Month-1, DateTime.Now.Year));
    eosDateEdit.DateTime = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", GetLastDayOfMonth(DateTime.Now.Month + 1),
        DateTime.Now.Month - 1, DateTime.Now.Year)); <-- FormatException occurs in this line.
}

private static int GetLastDayOfMonth(int month)
{
    // set return value to the last day of the month
    // for any date passed in to the method

    // create a datetime variable set to the passed in date
    DateTime dtTo = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, month, 1);

    // overshoot the date by a month
    dtTo = dtTo.AddMonths(1);

    // remove all of the days in the next month
    // to get bumped down to the last day of the
    // previous month
    dtTo = dtTo.AddDays(-(dtTo.Day));

    // return the last day of the month
    return dtTo.Day;
}
```

Lets say you get now if you run this 31/6/2010. I think its a valid date.
I have tested the date that is generated and its ok...this project never had this problem while was working in VS 2008.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm a little confused - why would 31/6/2010 be a valid date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FormatException` is caused by passing `31/6/2010` as an argument to `DateTime.Parse()`. 31/6/2010 is not a valid date - there are only 30 days in June.

If you need the last day in any month, you would be better off using the [`DateTime.DaysInMonth()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx) method. It takes both the month and year as arguments so it can deal with leap years.

Comment: @AlwaysBeCoding, since this response answers your question, you should make sure you check the outline of a "tick" next to the answer to mark it as "accepted".